# Export Access VBA Recordset To Single Row In Excel

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, recordset

I am trying to write some VBA to export a recordset from Access to Excel.  I have finally come down to the below export process, but it exports to columns A and B, and I want all of the data to be exported to row 2.

What would be the proper protocol/syntax to export to row 2?

```
Do While Not rsone.EOF
   columnNum = 1
   rowNum = rowNum + 1
   For Each fieldsss In rsone.Fields
       newExcelApp.Cells(rowNum, columnNum) = fieldsss.Value
     columnNum = columnNum + 1
   Next fieldsss
   rsone.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kurtz's answer was nearly right, but he forgot to stop resetting the column number, making each next record overwrite the previous one.

Use this:

```vb
columnNum = 1
Do While Not rsone.EOF
   For Each fieldsss In rsone.Fields
       newExcelApp.Cells(2, columnNum).Value = fieldsss
     columnNum = columnNum + 1
   Next fieldsss
   rsone.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: That's what happens when you're falling asleep while typing :)